# SQL Convert in Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, pivot

I've got a big long view query that I'm trying to create as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [iFix].[UF90NIRHistorian]
    AS
    SELECT 
        PARSENAME(TagName,2)            As [TagName],
        CONVERT(DATETIME,[TimeStamp])   As [TimeStamp], 
        CONVERT(FLOAT,Value)            As [Value]
    FROM OPENQUERY(IFIX_HISTORIAN, 
    '
    SET
        StartTime={ts ''2014-02-06 00:00:00''},
        SamplingMode=Calculated,
        CalculationMode=Average,
        IntervalMilliseconds=1Hour,
        RowCount=0
    SELECT * FROM ihRawData WHERE 
        TagName LIKE *.UF90n_TS_SP.F_CV OR
        TagName LIKE *.UF90n_DMB_SP.F_CV OR
        TagName LIKE *.SW_U680_01.F_CV OR
        TagName LIKE *.PD_U680_01.F_CV OR
        TagName LIKE *.FW_U680_01.F_CV
    ')
    PIVOT(
        AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT,Value) As Value)
        FOR [TagName] In (
            [UF90n_DMB_SP],
            [UF90N_TS_SP],
            [SW_U680_01],
            [PD_U680_01],
            [FW_U680_01])
        ) AS p
```

I'm getting a syntax error on the line after the PIVOT command when I'm trying to convert the Value column from a string to a float.  This error goes away if I create the view without the pivot, then pivot the results of that as a second view.  Is there any way I can keep this as one view and fix that syntax error?

Comment: can you actually post the error message?

Comment: You can't apply the `convert` in that place (`AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT,Value) As Value)`).  You have to convert the data prior to applying the `avg()`.

Comment: The error message is:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting the value field in the select then why do you need to convert it again in the pivot statement?  I tried a similar pivot statement with one of my tables and after casting the selected value to a different type then pivoting on it it worked fine.  Perhaps I am missing something but seems your second conversion is not needed.

Comment: Without the conversion I get an error saying I can't average a varchar.  I also tried renaming the column something different in the select statement and I got an error saying that it couldn't find the column.